# Audited: undefined method `associated' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, acts-as-audited

So I have a `Entry` model with a column called `created_by` which I would like to default to the first `User` who created the entry. I installed audited and in my `Entry` model I have:

```
belongs_to :user
audited :associated_with => :user
```

Similarly in my `User` model I have the following statements:

```
has_many :entries     
has_associated_audits
```

In my entries form, I was trying to create a `hidden_field` in which I was trying to set `created_by` to be equal to the the associated user of the first audit on the entry. However I'm getting this error, when I try to load the form view:

```
undefined method `associated' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the code in the view:

```
 .field
   = f.label :created_by
 %br
   = f.hidden_field :created_by, value: @entry.audits.first.associated
```

And here is the code in the `entries_controller` where I set `@entry` in the view:

```
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
    authorize! :create, @entry

    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @entry.project_id = @project.id
    authorize! :update, :read, @project
  end
```

I realize that, intuitively, it doesn't make much sense to call @entry.audits in the event of creating 
a new audit, since it has not yet been saved. Should I set the value of `@entry.created_by` after I call `@entry.save` in the `create` method of the controller? Not really sure about what is the most practical approach to take here.

Thanks,

Micha'el.

Comment: @Damien I think it's always the case that @entry.audits will be nil if @entry = Entry.new and hasn't been saved yet. Which makes me wonder where the best place to set the `created_by` field if not at moment of creating the `@entry` I supposed i could wrap the `hidden_field` stuff with a `if @entry.audits` in which case I could, assuming the entry has already been created, set the `created_by` value to what I want it to be.

Comment: @Damien although that seems a little wonky.

Comment: I'd agree that you shouldn't be setting the `created_by` attribute in the form, set it from within the controller, before `@entry.save`. There is no need to save the entry to get the user, you should know who the user is via `current_user`. You could add callback validations to ensure this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is remove the `created_by` hidden field from the form (that is easily intercepted), and instead set from within the controller before the `entry` is saved using `current_user` (or alternative) to access the user creating the entry.

```
def create_entry
  @entry.created_by = current_user
  @entry.save
end
```

I wouldn't consider it important to assign the `created_by` user after the audit has been saved via `@entry.audits.first.associated` because those audits should be associated to the same `current_user`. If that isn't the case, you have bigger problems on your hands.